# баш поиск картинки на imdb

Tags: javascript, linux, bash, thumbnails

есть такое приложение, https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/imdb-thumbnailer/, делает эскизы к видеофайлам по их имени, подставляя соответствующую картинку(постер) с imdb.com, я его немного подредактировал и оно исправно работало с файловым менеджером caja(mate), но с недавних пор скрипт перестал искать картинку на imdb, видимо они изменили на своем сайте движок, так как интерфейс сайта поменялся, и не могу разобраться, кто разбирается в баш, помогите.
проблема вроде кроется в этих секциях:

```
var () { local return ; "${@:3}" ; eval $1$2\$return;}

this ()
{
    return=${E#* }
    eval local ${return%/}
    return=${!1}
}

rdom () { local IFS=\> ; read -d \< E C ;}

get_grabber_picture ()
{
    if [[ $1 ]]; then
        id=$1
        id=${id%%:*}

        while rdom; do
            #if [[ $E = *'class="poster'* ]]; then
            if [[ $E = *'class="poster"'* ]]; then
                rdom;rdom;

                if [[ $E != *add_photo_text* ]]; then
                    var icon = this src
                fi
                break
            fi
        done < <(wget -U firefox -qO - "https://www.imdb.com/title/$id/")

        [[ $icon ]] && grabber_picture=${icon%@*}@.png    #${icon%@@*}@@.png #_V1._SX512_SY512_.png
        #[[ $icon ]] && grabber_picture=${icon%@@*}@@._V1._SX${size}_SY${size}_.png
    fi
}
```

[ссылка на скрипт](https://pastebin.com/h5uwQGuY)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

картинку можно получить

```
wget -U firefox -O- https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0109830/ | sed -rn 's/^.*"image":"([^"]+?)".*$/\1/p'
```

Сама функция получится такой

```
get_grabber_picture ()
{
    if [[ $1 ]]; then
        id=$1
        id=${id%%:*}

        icon=$(wget -U firefox -qO - "http://www.imdb.com/title/$id" | sed -rn 's/^.*"image":"([^"]+?)".*$/\1/p')

        [[ $icon ]] && grabber_picture=$icon
    fi
}
```

Comment: Cпасибо! Работает!

Comment: Я так понимаю, что функции var (), this () и rdom () теперь не имеют смысла?

Comment: @agafron я не знаю как с ними работать) так что да